# Dictionaries with List of Lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have two lists of lists: one contains the column names for a future data frame, the other contains values for those keys. I am trying to map the column names (keys) to the values.

Current code:

```
new_dict = dict(zip(l_list, v_list))

df = pd.DataFrame([new_dict], columns = new_dict.keys())
df.to_csv('Test_Services.csv', index = False, header = True)
```

Where `l_list` is my column names and `v_list` is the values

example:

```
l1 = [[col1, col2, col3], [col1, col2, col3, col4]]
l2 = [[v1, v2, v3], [ v1, v2, v3, v4]]
```

Ultimately I am trying to create a dataframe from these results. Some of the results will have more/less column names and will need a nan input.

example output:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
v1, v2, v3, nan
v1, v2, v3, v4
```

I am looping through a large list to gather the columns and values, most will have the same columns although some may differ. What would be the best way to have the infromation input to a Pandas Dataframe?

Comment: `l_list` looks like `l1` and `v_list` looks like `l2`? If yes, didn't this raise an error `dict(zip(l_list, v_list))`?

Comment: I got a hashable error from lists

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) method

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([dict(zip(x, y)) for x,y in zip(l1, l2)])
print(df)

  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   v1   v2   v3  NaN
1   v1   v2   v3   v4
```